# How to combine lists for universal function in C#?

Tags: c#, list, class

I hope the question isnt too confusing, I have been trying to combine different types of lists into one function without a lot of code but I dont know how.
This is the scenario:

I have a few classes (TClass1.cs, TClass2.cs, TClass3.cs, TClass4.cs, ...) all similar like this:

```
namespace Polly
{
    public class TClass1
    {
        public string Box1 { get; set; }
        public string Box2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I use them as lists:

```
    public List<TClass1> List1 = new List<TClass1>(); 
    public List<TClass2> List2 = new List<TClass2>(); 
    public List<TClass3> List3 = new List<TClass3>();
```

And currently Im using them in the Main.cs as following:

```
public class Polly
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (value == 1)
        {
            //100 rows calculating string f
            string f = List1.Box1;
        }
        else if (value == 2)
        {
            //100 rows calculating string f
            string f = List2.Box1;
        }
        else if (value == 3)
        {
            //100 rows calculating string f
            string f = List3.Box1;
        }
    }
}
```

Since all the lists are basically the same and copy and pasted I would like to calculate string f only once like this way:

```
public class Polly
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (value == 1)
        {
            GetString(List1);
        }
        else if (value == 2)
        {
            GetString(List2);
        }
        else if (value == 3)
        {
            GetString(List3);
        }
    }

    private string GetString(List<> ls)
    {
         //100 rows calculating string f
         string f = ls.Box1;
         return f;
    }
}
```

The only problem is, what type of List am I supposed to use since it varries from list to list (TClass1, TClass2, etc)?:

```
 private string GetString(List<WHATDOIPUTINHERE?> ls){}
```

Comment: You'll need inheritance. Make a class with these properties and then create the derivate classes from this class.  But your code seems weird and it's hard to understand what's your intention. If you can't have a single class and need to pass them anyway, you can use `<Object>` but the properties will be unknown.

Comment: If you are going to use `if-else/if-else` -  just use `swiitch/case` instead.

Comment: @Phiter You could not use `List<Object>` because `List<T>` is invariant.

Comment: @JonathonChase It's been a while since I last worked with C#. What does invariant mean?

Comment: @Phiter It means that you can only use the type originally specified. If a function takes a `List<object>` argument, you can only give it a `List<object>`. Trying to give it a `List<string>` will throw a compilation error about being unable to convert from `List<string>` to `List<object>`

Comment: Why do you need different classes if they are all similar? It would help us to understand if you showed us the real classes.

Comment: Perhaps he could use `List<dynamic>` then, which is obviously a terrible idea.

Comment: @bravobyte Do all of your classes have a Box1 property?

Comment: @Phiter The restriction is on the generic type `List<T>`, `List<dynamic>` will have the same problem.

Comment: You cannot do this `string f = List1.Box1;` because `Box1` is defined in `Class1`. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, thus I can't help

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; there are many problems with it. You're also missing samples of the other two classes. Please put up a sample that people can copy/paste and that can be used as the basis for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class should inherit from an interface

```
interface IBox1
{
    string Box1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your classes will implement it:

```
public class TClass1 : IBox1
{
    public string Box1 { get; set; }
    public string Box2 { get; set; }

}
```

Then your lists can be of the derived type:

```
List<TClass1> List1 = new List<TClass1>();
```

And you can add TClass1 objects to it:

```
List1.Add(new TClass1());
```

And your method definition, it should be expanded upon.

```
 private string GetString(List<Box1Interface> ls) {
        return "";
    }
```

and your method call.  This includes a cast to the interface before the call.

```
GetString(List1.ConvertAll(x => (IBox1)x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all these classes have the properties `Box1` and `Box2`, you could derive them all from a base class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Box1 { get; set; }
    public string Box2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public int AdditionalProp { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 : BaseClass
{
    public double YetAnotherlProp { get; set; }
}

public class Class3 : BaseClass
{ }

public class Class4 : BaseClass
{ }
```

Then create an array of lists typed as `IEnumerable<BaseClass>[]` (here with sample data):

```
public IEnumerable<BaseClass>[] _enumLists = new IEnumerable<BaseClass>[] {
    new List<Class1>{ new Class1 { Box1 = "a1" }, new Class1 { Box1 = "a2" }, new Class1 { Box1 = "a3" } },
    new List<Class2>{ new Class2 { Box1 = "b1" }, new Class2 { Box1 = "b2" }, new Class2 { Box1 = "b3" } },
    new List<Class3>{ new Class3 { Box1 = "c1" }, new Class3 { Box1 = "c2" }, new Class3 { Box1 = "c3" } },
    new List<Class4>{ new Class4 { Box1 = "d1" }, new Class4 { Box1 = "d2" }, new Class4 { Box1 = "d3" } },
};
```

Since the interface is declared as

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

... it is covariant and lets you combine the lists for read access and enumeration only.

You can then get the combined string easily

```
private string GetString(int value)
{
    return String.Join(", ", _enumLists[value - 1].Select(item => item.Box1));
}
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetString(2)); // Prints: c1, c2, c3
```